# Error "The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set" when trying to update group

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to successfully create groups in PHP using Microsoft Graph v1.0.

However, I get the following error when trying to update the same group:

> The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

How can I resolve this error?

### Code

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/104e2256-6bfc-40e8-a357-fa76cc36eb64";
$body = "{'allowExternalSenders': false, 'visibility': 'Private'}";

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($output, true);

print var_dump($json);
```

### Output

```
["error"]=> array(3) { 
    ["code"]=> string(10) "BadRequest" 
    ["message"]=> string(65) "The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set" 
    ["innerError"]=> array(2) { 
        ["request-id"]=> string(36) "26a5413a-17cc-4de8-b97d-00ffbc080098" 
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-01-04T17:03:05" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What OAuth grant are you using to obtain `$token`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  We are using the client_credentials grant type.  I was able to use the same token to successfully create the group.  I get this error when trying to update the group with the same token.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  I was able to isolate the problem.  If I set `$body = "{'visibility': 'Private'}";` **it works**.  If I set `$body = "{'allowExternalSenders': false}";` I get this **error**: `{ ["error"]=> array(3) { ["code"]=> string(17) "ErrorAccessDenied" ["message"]=> string(50) "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again." ["innerError"]=> array(2) { ["request-id"]=> string(36) "5c34513e-a6ab-46d7-a04a-f740f2a69a06" ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-01-04T22:13:01" } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Application permissions (i.e. scopes applied when using Client Credentials).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> Only a subset of the group API pertaining to core group administration and management support application and delegated permissions. All other members of the group API, including updating autoSubscribeNewMembers, support only delegated permissions. See [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups) for examples.

From [Known Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups):

> Examples of group features that support only delegated permissions:
>
> - Group conversations, events, photo
> - External senders, accepted or rejected senders, group subscription
> - User favorites and unseen count